# Sql statement with multi ANDs querying the same column

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I don't know if the title of the post is the appropriate. I have the following table

[image]

and an Array in php with some items, `parsed_array`. What I want to do is to find all the SupermarketIDs which have all the items of the `parsed_array`.

For example, if `parsed_array` contains `[111,121,131]` I want the result to be `21` which is the ID of the Supermarket that contains all these items.

I tried to do it like that:

```
$this->db->select('SupermarketID'); 
$this->db->from('productinsupermarket');
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($parsed_array); $i++)
    {
      $this->db->where('ItemID', $parsed_array[$i]);
    }
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

If there is only one item in the `parsed_array` the result is correct because the above is equal to

```
SELECT SupermarketID 
FROM productinsupermarket
WHERE ItemID=parsed_array[0];
```

but if there are more than one items, lets say two, is equal to

```
SELECT SupermarketID 
FROM productinsupermarket
WHERE ItemID=parsed_array[0]
AND ItemID=parsed_array[1];
```

which of course return an empty table. Any idea how can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where_in` in codeigniter as below,

```
if(count($parsed_array) > 0)
{
    $this->db->where_in('ItemID', $parsed_array);
}
```

[Active record class in codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: If this actually solved the problem, I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways of generating the result you want, either a self join (no fun to generate with a dynamic number of items) or using `IN`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

I can't really tell you how to generate it using CodeIgniter, I assume you're better at that than I am :)

```
SELECT SupermarketID 
FROM productinsupermarket
WHERE ItemID IN (111,121,131)       -- The 3 item id's you're looking for
GROUP BY SupermarketID
HAVING COUNT(ItemId) = 3;           -- All 3 must match
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09c4f/1).

EDIT: As @ypercube mentions below, if the ItemId can show up more than once for a SupermarketID, you'll want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT ItemId)` to count only unique rows instead of counting every occurrence.

Comment: Two is an under-estimate; Here's a similar question with more than 10 answers for the same problem (relational division): [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: @ypercube Interesting link, I've only encountered the two :) Thanks.

Comment: You have my +1. The `GROUP BY / HAVING COUNT =n` is the most popular and easy to write (and usually without need for dynamic SQL). I think you have to add that it works only if the `(ItemID,SupermarketID)` combination is unique. Otherwise, the condition has to be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ItemId) = 3;   `

Answer (score 0):

Try an IN clause or multiple ORs:

```
SELECT SupermarketID 
FROM productinsupermarket
WHERE ItemID=parsed_array[0]
OR ItemID=parsed_array[1];
```